# how to create a rearrange cells in collection view with custom grid using swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to Swift .I have one scenario to implement. 
Consider a UICollectionView with flow layout and horizontal direction. By default, cells are ordered from top to bottom, left to right. Like this:

```
        1 4 7 10 13 16
        2 5 8 11 14 17
        3 6 9 12 15 18
```

In my case, the collection view is paged and it has been designed so that a specific number of cells fits in each page. Thus, a more natural ordering would be:

```
        1 2 3   10 11 12
        4 5 6 - 13 14 15
        7 8 9   16 17 18
```

And is there any way to implement re arranging cells among pages . Like inter change cell 1 and cell 11.

Please give me some idea how to achieve this.